# TFS. Changeset number. "Get Version"

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild, changeset

How can I build a Build with single Changeset#? or Changeset numbers related to specific one file.

My scenario:

- Changeset# 100 -> contains modified file X for problem Y
- Changeset# 99 -> contains modified file Y but for different problem Z
- Changeset# 98 -> contains modified file Z but for different problem W

I want to create a Build with just Changeset# 100. I don't want to include Changeset# 99 and 98 because that Changesets don't contain files related to file X. They contain different files Y and Z. That Changesets are not related to to Changeset# 100.

I want to include in my Build just files related to file X.

My steps:
Right click on the build: - Select "Queue Build" - Select "TF Version Control" tab - Type changeset number in "Get Version" for example changeset# 100

"Get version" is not working as I expected. It takes all Changeset numbers 100, 99. 98.

Answer (score 2):

When you specify a Changeset to build, you're really just saying "build whatever the build definition dictates at that point in time", rather than the latest version.

So, in your case specifying Changeset #100 is going to include #99 & #98.

You could probably achieve this by creating another branch, performing a cherry pick merge into it (just #100) then clone and edit the build definition but I think it would get messy pretty quickly.

I suspect that you might be better off looking at a branching structure that would allow you to work on these changes in isolation (feature branching maybe) and then merging to your mainline branch when ready for release.